# Does the position of the flash in compact cameras make a real difference in reducing red eye?

Tags: flash, compact-cameras, camera-design, red-eye

I am interested whether the position of the flash at the three examples of point and shoot cameras below would avoid or at least decrease the red eye effect. Or do you feel that all flashes are still close enough to the lens to cause red eye?

*The cameras are just used as examples!*

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: don't see any relationship of the cameras with the question... :(

Comment: it's about the flash of these cameras ;)

Comment: i see. i got it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the distance at which the picture is taken. [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-eye_effect):

> If direct flash must be used, a good rule of thumb is to separate the flash from the lens by 1/20 of the distance of the camera to the subject.  For example, if the subject is 2 meters (6 feet) away, the flash head should be at least 10 cm (4 inches) away from the lens.

2 meters is already pretty close for a portrait shot, and those cameras look like the distance between flash and lens is less than 10cm, so they'll probably still cause red eyes for all but extremely close shots.

To be exact, in order to avoid red eyes, you want the angle of reflection from the flash to the lens via the eye to be more than 2.5 degrees, which means an angular distance of at least 5 degrees:

[image]

But nowadays most cameras can emit a pre-flash that causes pupils to contract (reducing the effect) or even automatically remove red eyes in post-processing.

Comment: How should I measure the distance, the 10cm in this case? Horizontally or vertically?

Comment: @Morpho: I'd say that it should be measured directly, diagonally, if you will, since the eye's pupil is round.

Comment: By diagonally do you mean from the lens to the flash diagonally?

Comment: @Morpho: Yes, but not including the length of the lens. Basically, what matters is the angular distance as seen by the subject being photographted - it should be at least 3 degrees.

Comment: What do you mean by angular distance? Is there any diagram I can see to visualize it? :)

Comment: Morpho: see updated answer

Comment: Thank you very much, Michael! Can I ask where I can find this photo? :) Also, if I want to measure it having in mind the rule of thumb, the 10cm in our case, are measured as per the distance between the camera without the lens and the flash vertically. Am I right?

Comment: @Morpho: the diagram is from this website: http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/DigiCam/User-Guide/995/INTERNAL-FLASH/red-eye-reduction.html - and the measure would only be purely vertical if the flash is directly above the lens.

Comment: Thank you for sharing! Yes, this is my guess, too! But what happens if it is not above?

Comment: @Morpho: you just measure the distance. Why do you think that you can measure it only purely vertical or horizontal?

Comment: OK. I think I got it - I just measure the distance between the flash and the camera body without the lens either vertically or horizontally depending where the flash is located. Right?

Comment: @Morpho: correct